# React-Leaflet is creating two maps

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-leaflet

I am trying to create a minimap but for some reason, react-leaflet renders the map twice.
I think its the container is not big enough to contain the map so it translates it out but I don't get how big it's supposed to be.
The documentation doesn't really mention this.

```
   import React from 'react';
   import { MapContainer, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet';
        
    const MapStyle = {
      height: '100px',
      width: '100px',
    };
    
    const MiniMap = assetLocation => {
      return (
        <MapContainer center={[45.4, -75.7]} zoom={13} scrollWheelZoom={false} style={MapStyle}>
          <TileLayer url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" />
        </MapContainer>
      );
    };
```

I implement it inside Antd's grid system

```
<Row>
  <Space>
    <Col>
      <MiniMap assetLocation={item} />
      <NavButtons id={id} />
    </Col>
   <Col>{ ...otherComponents }</Col>
  </Space>
```

[image]

Comment: Where is the code of the actual map? I only see minimap' s code and the place you include it. Could you add the code of the actual and minimap together? Minimap comp should be a child of MapContainer and that does not seem to be the case in your code

Comment: The code is correct aren't you instancing it in 2 places?

Comment: @kboul what do you mean? I shared the MiniMap component --- MapContainer comes directly from the react-leaflet library. 
no, I am only instancing it once. it's actually one map but it's translating it cause it doesn't fit in the map container but even if I make the map container large it will still throw an error

Comment: Check this example [here](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/example-react-control) on the official docs. It has everything you need. One `MapContainer` that defines the big map and another one inside `MinimapControl`containing the minimap. The second one is a child of the first.

Comment: @kboul I'm not trying to have a minimap inside a Map. I think that is the confusion. I want my map to be a small square that's in my dashboard. Sorry for the confusion but the Minimap component is just a map that's small (maybe 300px x 300px)

Comment: ok solved it! Leaflet needs to import it's css as well. 
`import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing the Leaflet's CSS.
Just need to import it into the react component:

`import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';`